# IAB v3 buy intent is purchasing the item and not consuming it?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

im launching a purchase flow with 'android.test.purchased' and that works as expected, however when select 'buy' and completing the purchase it now 'owns' the item and wont let me purchase again, even though i've quite clearly got **mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);**

NOTE: I'm not getting ANY log feedback until after the purchase and it's telling me the items already owned.

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
            Log.d("KFF", "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);
            if (result.isFailure()) {

                if (result.toString().contains("3")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_User.this, "In app billing unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                else if (result.toString().contains("7")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_User.this, "Item already purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    int n = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(Add_User.this);
                    if (n != 0) {
                        // MAKE RED NAME = TRUE;
                    }
                }
                else if (result.toString().contains("6")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Add_User.this, "Fatal error in in app purchase",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (result.toString().contains("8")) {
                    redName = false;
                }
                return;
            }

            if (purchase.getSku().equals(RedName.SKU)) {
                // bought the premium upgrade!
                Log.d("KFF", "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
                mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);

            }

            /*
             * else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_INFINITE_GAS)) { // bought
             * the infinite gas subscription }
             */
        }
    };
```

-

```
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
            Log.d("KFF", "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

            if (result.isSuccess()) {

                Log.d("KFF", "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
                redName = true;
                ChkBox_red.setChecked(true);
                ChkBox_red.setEnabled(false);
                ChkBox_red.setText("Username will be red!");
            }
            else {
                // complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
                Log.d("KFF", "Error while consuming: " + result);
            }

            Log.d("KFF", "End consumption flow.");
        }
    };
```

-

```
 ChkBox_red = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.check_red );
        ChkBox_red.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {

                if ( isChecked )
                {
                    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.flagEndAsync();
                    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Add_User.this, RedName.SKU, 10002, 
                            mPurchaseFinishedListener);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi were you able to solve the issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I cannot remember sorry! I think it was either solved in the library or i found a manual fix, sorry to be of little help! If i remember i'll look into my code when i get home.